# Insert Extra fields added in the front end registration form to DB

Tags: database, forms, wpdb, user-registration

I have added some extra fields like first_name,middle name,last_name etc into the custom registration form. I want to add those details int the DB also. Now only username,email,Display name and user_nice name are inserted into the db. How can i add the extra fields added in the front end to the DB?

Following is the template i used to create login/Register/Forgot page

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Registration Template
*/
get_header();?>
<div id="login-register-password">

<?php global $user_ID, $user_identity; get_currentuserinfo(); if (!$user_ID) { ?>

<ul class="tabs_login">
    <li class="active_login"><a href="#tab1_login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2_login">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3_login">Forgot?</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container_login">
    <div id="tab1_login" class="tab_content_login">

        <?php $register = $_GET['register']; $reset = $_GET['reset']; if ($register == true) { ?>

        <h3>Success!</h3>
        <p>Check your email for the password and then return to log in.</p>

        <?php } elseif ($reset == true) { ?>

        <h3>Success!</h3>
        <p>Check your email to reset your password.</p>

        <?php } else { ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php" class="wp-user-form">
            <div class="username">
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e('Username');_e("/");_e("Email"); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="log" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_login)); ?>" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="11" />
            </div>
            <div class="password">
                <label for="user_pass"><?php _e('Password'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" value="" size="20" id="user_pass" tabindex="12" />
            </div>
            <div class="login_fields">
                <div class="rememberme">
                    <label for="rememberme">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="forever" checked="checked" id="rememberme" tabindex="13" /> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <?php do_action('login_form'); ?>
                <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php _e('Login'); ?>" tabindex="14" class="user-submit" />
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2_login" class="tab_content_login" style="display:none;">
        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        <p>We encourage you to do a one-time signup with us to be able to download content from this website</p>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" class="wp-user-form">
            <div class="username">
                <label for="title"><?php _e('Title'); ?>: </label>
                <Select>
                    <option>Mr</option>
                    <option>Ms</option>
                    <option>Mrs</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="username">
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e('First Name'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($first_name)); ?>" size="20" id="first_name" tabindex="101" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="username">
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e('Middle Name'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="middle_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($middle_name)); ?>" size="20" id="middle_name" tabindex="101" />
            </div>
            <div class="username">
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e('Last Name'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($last_name)); ?>" size="20" id="last_name" tabindex="101" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="username">
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e('Username'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="user_login" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_name)); ?>" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="101" required />
            </div>
            <div class="password">

                <label for="user_email"><?php _e('Email Address'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="user_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_email)); ?>" size="25" id="user_email" tabindex="102" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="password">
                <label for="organisation"><?php _e('Organisation'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="organisation" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_org)); ?>" size="25" id="organisation" tabindex="102" />
            </div>
            <div class="password">
                <label for="Designation"><?php _e('Designation'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="Designation" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_desig)); ?>" size="25" id="designation" tabindex="102"/>
            </div>
            <div class="password">
                <label for="Designation"><?php _e('Which Product are you interested in'); ?>: </label>
                <Select>
                    <option>COREDC</option>
                    <option>COREAE</option>
                    <option>COREQROPS</option>
                    <option>CORE Point Solutions</option>
                    <option>Just Exploring</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="width:100px;position:relative;float:left;margin: 7px 0 0 0;">
                <input type="button" name="user-cancel" value="<?php _e('Cancel'); ?>" id="user-cancel" tabindex="103" />
            </div>
            <div class="login_fields">
                <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>
                <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php _e('Sign up!'); ?>" class="user-signup" tabindex="103" />
                <?php $register = $_GET['register']; if($register == true) { echo '<p>Check your email for the password!</p>'; } ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?register=true" />
                <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3_login" class="tab_content_login" style="display:none;">
        <h3>Lose something?</h3>
        <p>Enter your username or email to reset your password.</p>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=lostpassword', 'login_post') ?>" class="wp-user-form">
            <div class="username">
                <label for="user_login" class="hide"><?php _e('Username or Email'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="user_login" value="" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="1001" />
            </div>
            <div class="login_fields">
                <?php do_action('login_form', 'resetpass'); ?>
                <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php _e('Reset my password'); ?>" class="user-submit" tabindex="1002" />
                <?php $reset = $_GET['reset']; if($reset == true) { echo '<p>A message will be sent to your email address.</p>'; } ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?reset=true" />
                <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } else { // is logged in ?>

<div class="sidebox">
    <h3>Welcome, <?php echo $user_identity; ?></h3>
    <div class="usericon">
        <?php global $userdata; get_currentuserinfo(); echo get_avatar($userdata->ID, 60); ?>

    </div>
    <div class="userinfo">
        <p>You&rsquo;re logged in as <strong><?php echo $user_identity; ?></strong></p>
        <p>
            <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('index.php'); ?>">Log out</a> | 
            <?php if (current_user_can('manage_options')) { 
                echo '<a href="' . admin_url() . '">' . __('Admin') . '</a>'; } else { 
                echo '<a href="' . admin_url() . 'profile.php">' . __('Profile') . '</a>'; } ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387127 See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068

Comment: There are timestamps on these questions. You waited maybe five minutes before cross-posting. Sorry, but "I'm not getting an answer here" is hard to swallow. You just didn't feel like waiting and posting them effectively simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Why the downvotes for using user meta? That's how I do it, I store all the extra profile stuff in `wp_usermeta` table by utilizing [`update_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta).

```
<?php

// first validate all $_POST data
$validated = $this->validate_and_sanitize();

$username = $validated['uname'];
$password = $validated['pass'];
$email = $validated['email'];

$new_user_id = wp_create_user($username, $password, $email);

if ( is_wp_error($new_user_id) && array_key_exists('existing_user_login', $new_user_id->errors)) {
    $return['status'] = 2; // email entered is already in use
    $return['msg'] = 'Email entered is already in use';
    echo json_encode($return);
    exit;
}
if( !is_wp_error($new_user_id) ) {
    if (isset( $validated['phone'] ) && strlen(trim($phone)) > 0) { 
        $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($validated['phone']);
        $umeta_id_phone = update_user_meta( $new_user_id, 'phone', $phone ); 
    }
    if (isset( $validated['phone'] ) && strlen(trim($city)) > 0) {
        $city = mysql_real_escape_string($validated['city']);
        $umeta_id_city = update_user_meta( $new_user_id, 'city', $city ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: "Why the downvotes for using user meta?". Why are you asking? Add your upvote to the other answer and it's fine.

Comment: Where shall I put this code? In my template file??

Comment: You can, but in my case it's inside a plugin because this functionality should not be theme-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra fields on `(user meta tables)` using this function [add_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) and also [can delete_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_user_meta), [get_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta), [update_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta).

Answer (score -1):

You need to save those to usermeta table with key,value pair..

Comment: Might you take yourself a minute and consider explaining the _how_ and _why_? I consider adding my upvote as well. Or an upvote in case the edit makes it better.